# Error when I open new view in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I have that error when I want open new view and I don't know what does it mean.
I run that code:

```
func openMenu(){
    let storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let vc: UIViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MenuViewController") as UIViewController
    self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

And the error is:

Warning: Attempt to present  on  whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

I have that Swift code:
[Swift](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5J5xZ.png)
And I want execute with Objective-C the Swift code.
[Objective-C](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c3LLl.png)

Comment: Inside which method do you have this block of code?

Comment: in a void normal method.

func openMenu(){
        let storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let vc: UIViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MenuViewController") as UIViewController
        self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

Comment: Can you show the complete error message and the code where the error occurs. You may also want to  review http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask so that you can write the most informative questions you can.

Comment: Please update your question  with the new code - it's pretty hard to read code in the comments :)

Comment: I change my question @fragilecat

Comment: Please excuse me, but I don't understand what you are mean.

Answer (score 0):

replace the line:

```
self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

with:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
    self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
})
```

See if it works!

or

why don't you create a segue and call it using:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if (segue.identifier == "Load View") {
        // pass data to next view
    }
}
```

Comment: that don't run to me.

Comment: Can you update your question and show me your storyboard?

Comment: Where do you call the  openMenu();? on viewDidLoad?

Comment: No, I create a button with swift and the method call when I press the button.

Comment: Update my answer, why you not try make a segue call?

Comment: It seems that you are trying to instantiate view controller which is not present on that storyboard,please make sure it is on the same storyboard

Comment: How can I open swift view from Objective-C? @AjinkyaPatil

Comment: @juan what do you mean by that please explain

Comment: I can open swift view with Objective-C (I want to say, in storyboard I have a view which it have associated a swift view and I can open that view with swift, what I have to do?) @AjinkyaPatil

Comment: @Juan I am not getting what are you trying to say can you explain with the help of  screenshot

Comment: Show the photos which are in my post. @AjinkyaPatil